# Can not enter a new master password in pgadmin4 v5.7

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am working with two versions of pgAdmin4, v5.7 and v7.4. With v7.4 I don´t have any trouble with connecting to my local or remote servers, however with v5.7 I have encountered problem with logging. It worked week before, but it doesn´t work now. I can not figure it out why it logs error "(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: server.hostaddr".

```
 [SQL: SELECT server.id AS server_id, server.user_id AS server_user_id, server.servergroup_id AS server_servergroup_id, server.name AS server_name, server.host AS server_host, server.hostaddr AS server_hostaddr, server.port AS server_port, server.maintenance_db AS server_maintenance_db, server.username AS server_username, server.password AS server_password, server.save_password AS server_save_password, server.role AS server_role, server.ssl_mode AS server_ssl_mode, server.comment AS server_comment, server.discovery_id AS server_discovery_id, server.db_res AS server_db_res, server.passfile AS server_passfile, server.sslcert AS server_sslcert, server.sslkey AS server_sslkey, server.sslrootcert AS server_sslrootcert, server.sslcrl AS server_sslcrl, server.sslcompression AS server_sslcompression, server.bgcolor AS server_bgcolor, server.fgcolor AS server_fgcolor, server.service AS server_service, server.connect_timeout AS server_connect_timeout, server.use_ssh_tunnel AS server_use_ssh_tunnel, server.tunnel_host AS server_tunnel_host, server.tunnel_port AS server_tunnel_port, server.tunnel_username AS server_tunnel_username, server.tunnel_authentication AS server_tunnel_authentication, server.tunnel_identity_file AS server_tunnel_identity_file, server.tunnel_password AS server_tunnel_password, server.shared AS server_shared, server.kerberos_conn AS server_kerberos_conn, servergroup_1.id AS servergroup_1_id, servergroup_1.user_id AS servergroup_1_user_id, servergroup_1.name AS servergroup_1_name 
FROM server LEFT OUTER JOIN servergroup AS servergroup_1 ON servergroup_1.id = server.servergroup_id 
WHERE (server.user_id = ? OR server.shared = 1) AND server.servergroup_id = ?]
[parameters: (1, 1)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: server.hostaddr

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\~\web\pgadmin\browser\utils.py", line 315, in dispatch_request
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\~\web\pgadmin\browser\utils.py", line 350, in children
    children = self.get_children_nodes(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\~\web\pgadmin\browser\utils.py", line 371, in get_children_nodes
    children.extend(module.get_nodes(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\~\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 208, in get_nodes
    servers = self.get_servers(servers, hide_shared_server, gid)
  File "C:\~\web\pgadmin\browser\server_groups\servers\__init__.py", line 174, in get_servers
    for server in all_servers:
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3535, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3560, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\~\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

The logs traces back to several py files, ex. app.py, utils.py etc.

I've tried to reinstall pgAdmin, but nothing works. Any suggestions on what I could try? Thank you!

Update:
I´ve come to conclusion that the problem lies in the configuration file ~AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\pgadmin4.db. So I unninstalled and removed all postgresql tools, including data connecting with pgadmin in user´s AppData.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use such an old version, known to have many bugs?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, one of our application runs on an old postgres db. In the near future db and a whole app will be updated, but for now we need it as it is.

Comment: I solved the problem and edited the original post.

Comment: Does it now work with both versions?  I would have thought that any given pgadmin4.db format is only going to work with one of those pgadmin4 versions or the other, not with both.